# :after transition on hover make elements move

Tags: html, css

I put an image on :after, with a translation on :hover. It makes other unrelated elements move on Chrome, with OS X (Firefox: unresponsive, and Safari : doesn't support transition effect)

I tried without transition, works fine.

I have this on several elements, and they all have this same problem as long as transition and :after are involved.

Here's the html:

```
<a href="work-timburton.html"  class="btn-call-to-action">See the project</a>
```

and the css:

```
.btn-call-to-action {
  background: #8e8287;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #f5f3e2;
  padding: 10px 70px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap; }

.btn-call-to-action:after {
  content: url('../img/general-white-arrow.svg?1370787761');
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  width: 35px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }

.btn-call-to-action:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: translatex(6px);
  -moz-transform: translatex(6px);
  -o-transform: translatex(6px);
  -ms-transform: translatex(6px);
  transform: translatex(6px); }
```

[and the live version here.](http://aurelieremia.be/tfa/)

Comment: On Windows it looks fine in Chrome.

Comment: Sometimes I have the same problem and I'm not sure why this happens... All I know is that in some cases it helps to add -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden to the elements affected.